# Facebook White Screen But Only On Particular Account

Tags: facebook

I've had a problem with Facebook.com for a few days now. Every time I load the website @ https://www.facebook.com it will just take a few seconds and then display a white page. The source of the page is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" id="facebook" class="no_js">
<head><meta charset="utf-8" /><script>function envFlush(a){function b(c){for(var d in a)c[d]=a[d];}if(window.requireLazy){window.requireLazy(['Env'],b);}else{window.Env=window.Env||{};b(window.Env);}}envFlush({"ajaxpipe_token":"AXgRWhMTFIL_juHq","lhsh":"KAQF0BXye","khsh":"0`sj`e`rm`s-0fdu^gshdoer-0gc^eurf-3gc^eurf;1;enbtldou;fduDmdldourCxO`ld-2YLMIuuqSdptdru;qsnunuxqd;rdoe-0unjdojnx0"});</script><script>CavalryLogger=false;</script><noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=/?_fb_noscript=1" /></noscript><meta name="referrer" content="origin-when-crossorigin" id="meta_referrer" /><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yf/r/rTRM3thxxyG.css" data-bootloader-hash="nVu0I" data-permanent="1" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yX/r/h3ydpK_uuri.css" data-bootloader-hash="zp4CG" data-permanent="1" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/ym/r/T7fKvPc0GuV.css" data-bootloader-hash="2S8io" data-permanent="1" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yu/r/Ld1C_Jcgl5j.css" data-bootloader-hash="/JEly" data-permanent="1" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yW/r/m6m6Y7RpsEs.js" data-bootloader-hash="5WJdo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>require("TimeSlice").guard(function() {(require("ServerJSDefine")).handleDefines([["CSSLoaderConfig",[],{"timeout":5000,"loadEventSupported":true},619]]);new (require("ServerJS"))().handle({"require":[["Bootloader","loadEarlyResources",[],[{"RmDcU":{"type":"js","src":"https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yL\/r\/uKsBDyzJwJh.js","crossOrigin":1},"5zC\/8":{"type":"js","src":"https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/y0\/r\/64jGxSfxJ36.js","crossOrigin":1},"pFHnJ":{"type":"js","src":"https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yp\/r\/K6ojr4ngQRr.js","crossOrigin":1},"P0eje":{"type":"js","src":"https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/y2\/r\/Wn1AFwUyuPt.js","crossOrigin":1},"q\/AOh":{"type":"js","src":"https:\/\/static.xx.fbcdn.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yn\/r\/r40PYeaPQsy.js","crossOrigin":1}}]]]});}, "ServerJS define", {"root":true})();</script>
```

I tried deleting all cookies, history, empty cache etc. and that allowed me to get to the login screen. When I login using my account it gives me the white screen, however I created a dummy account for this problem and logged in using a new account, completely fresh and it worked fine...

Not too sure what's going on here since it seems to be account specific, and it's not like I've misused the site... Anyone have any insight into this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not programming related. Contact Facebook’s end user support instead.

Comment: I would if I could. I can't even get onto Facebook support, help or anything else. It's not related to my local network since other devices in my house work running Facebook on other Facebook accounts.

Comment: You said your new “dummy account” worked fine – so use that to go to the help section and contact support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or just answer the question with a fix and be a little more human and compassionate. The fix by the way is simple - create a business FB profile at business.facebook.com, using the same email address as the affected FB account. Once in on that, change views to your personal profile and your account should be back working normally.

Comment: I tried the fix mentioned above. I'm seeing a blank page on business.facebook.com too! this is a bit ridiculous to be honest. is there a real fix to the problem?

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. @John where did you see this fix?

Answer (score -1):

You will need to submit the code to Facebook as its an issue accessing their server. That's a timeout, try logging in with a VPN set from a different area. Sometimes going from Instagram to Facebook cross-platform will cause a similar issue is an authentication token isn't given in a timely manner.

If that doesn't work report the code to Facebook so they can fix the timeout error.

Comment: Please don't invite people to contact you directly, that's not allowed in posts on Stack Overflow.